# Как изменить в Spinner цвет текста, фона. И форму опускающего списка в Android

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я читал на разных сайтах. Но так-как там реализовано у меня не получается. Ответ на вопрос может быть большим . Но если вы ответите подробно. Я буду вам ОЧЕНЬ Благодарен. Спасибо вам за то что помогаете новичкам разработчикам

Comment: код нужно прикреплять в виде текста а не картинок!!!

Comment: Чтобы сказать здесь "спасибо" - не надо это писать много раз в комментариях, нужно отметить ответ верным (нажать на галочку слева от ответа, который вам помог, чтобы она стала зеленой). Если вы еще больше благодарны, то можете и поднять репутацию (стрелочка вверх слева от ответа). Это касается всех  ответов па ваши вопросы

Answer (score 4):

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("Пункт 1");
    add("Пункт 2");
    add("Пункт 3");
    add("Пункт 4");
    add("Пункт 5");
}};
CustomAdapter adapter = new  CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.item_spinner_title, R.layout.item_spinner_dropdown, list);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("logs", "Выбран пункт " + list.get(position));
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
});
```

Вот адаптер для спинера. Можешь передать в него свои вьюхи

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private int mResource; // id вьюхи для свернутого списка
    private int dropDownResource; // id вьюхи для выпадающего списка
    private List<String> items;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int mResource, int dropDownResource, List<String> items) {
        super(context, mResource, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.mResource = mResource;
        this.dropDownResource = dropDownResource;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        TextView tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(items.get(position));
        //Здесь делаешь с tvTitle то что тебе нужно. Меняешь фон, цвет текста и т.д.
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(dropDownResource, parent, false);
        TextView tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(items.get(position));
        //Здесь делаешь с tvTitle то что тебе нужно. Меняешь фон, цвет текста и т.д.
        return view;
    }
}
```

***item_spinner_title***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

***item_spinner_dropdown***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Comment: String[] dayOfWeek = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};                             
  CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.row, dayOfWeek);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter); Я добавил этот класс. Но в MainActivity когда добавляю этот адаптер выходит ошибка на месте - new. И пишется типа int вид нужен. Хотя я массив int тоже делал/ В консоли выходит вот эта ошибка:  CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                                ^
  required: Context,int,int,List<String>
  found: MainActivity,int,String[]

Comment: Ты видишь что принимает конструктор? 2 лэйаута и список, а ты передаешь 1 лэйаут и массив :-|

Comment: Я прикрепил картинку к вопросу своему. Посмотри пожалуйста в чем ошибка? Я немножко изменил код

Comment: OMG Зачем ты засунул туда массив? ArrayAdapter принимает список! Список, Карл, список!!!

Comment: Почему ты не смотришь на конструкторы и пытаешься впихнуть невпихуемое?

Comment: Ахпхах. Соррян. Я добавил! Всё равно ошибка выходит. В другой активити тоже все изменил добавил всё равно не выходит. И кстати вот здесь показано что массив можно добавить в Адаптер вниз посмотри: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/spinner.php

Comment: Какую ошибку выводит?

Comment: Пожалуста отправь мне полностью код! Если есть возможность... итак так ты мне помог ТЕБЕ БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО! Там очень много ошибок выводится

Comment: @onegingek дополнил ответ. Код рабочий 100% Свеженаписанный и отлаженный. Хочешь сказать спасибо, ставь галочку)

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо! Только смотри, я смог это применить для одного Спиннера. А потом я должен был это все применить к 5 спинерам. Применил и там форма опускающего списка есть все есть, все работает. Только выбранный элемент из списка не появляется в самом спиннере как выбранный, он бывает пустым. Почему? Связано ли это с тем что спиннеров много? Или я должен для каждого спиннера создатьсвою форму xml. А класс CostumAdapter оставить..

Comment: Я сейчас попробовал тоже сделать 5 спиннеров, все работает как часики

Comment: Проверяю проверяю. Не получается у меня. Ну и ладно. Еще буду проверять. Ты лучший Брат. Огромное Спасибо тебе *Черное сердечко*

Answer (score 1):

Если ты новичок то возможно тебе будет проще взять готовую библиотеку и вперёд. Не надо придумывать то что уже есть.
Например эта библиотека:

https://github.com/skydoves/PowerSpinner/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!